# ABAC + LDAP server/ (Active Directory) with Fortress on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, xacml, abac, fortress

I am kindly seeking guidance and a little help on implementing XACML ABAC with Active Directory authentication on Kubernetes.

We have a major project at the hospital we are working on, and authorisation and permissions are are great concern. After a digging around, We determined that ABAC and XACML would be our best shot and handling consents and permissions.

However we also have Active Directory server from a different unit, and it is what we are meant to use at the moment for authentication into the cluster . We are meant/want to run a kubernetes cluster on which  different pods with different apps are to run. Any guidance and help for us? Could Fortress be an option towards achieving this? (ABAC)+(external LDAP server/ Active Directory) on Kubernetes.

Thank you.